# Do...While won't stop

Tags: c++, arrays, do-while

So I am making a program for an assignment and at the moment I am trying to get user input and trying to make it fit a certain form.

For example the user is to type in a date with the format mm/yyyy.
If the user does not type it in that format it will just reprompt the user.

so far this is my small loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int findSlash(char[], int);
int findLastEle(char[]);

int main() {
//variables
char expDate[7];
int expLast, expEle;
int expLen;

do{
cout << "Enter experation (form mm/yyyy): ";
cin.getline(expDate, 7);
expLen = strlen(expDate);
expEle = findSlash(expDate, expLen);
expLast = findLastEle(expDate);

}while(expEle != (expLast - 4));

return 0;
}

//findSlash function (finds slash place in array)
int findSlash(char array[], int arrayLen){
int r, dec = 0;

for(r = 0; r < arrayLen; r++){
    if(array[r] == '/'){
        break;
    }
    else{
        dec++;
    }
}

return dec;
}
```

The loop is suppose just reprompt at the moment if '/' is not in the right spot but the loop instead just spams the cout statement and I don't know why its doing that. Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: What have you tried? something like single step debugging? outputting your loop invariants and its dependent data each steps?

Comment: Good start would be to add the debug output that would output the values returned from `findSlash` and `findLastEle` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cin.getline(expDate, 7)`, if it does not find a newline delimiter, will extract at most 6 characters from `cin` and fill the last element of `expDate` with a null character. That's because the second argument is meant to only give the size of the buffer in the first argument so that it doesn't write past the end of the buffer. When `getline` stops extracting because it has reached the buffer limit, it sets the fail bit to true. Any further attempt to extract will just fail immediately.

To fit the entire date in the array (which is 7 characters long) along with the null character, you'll need your array to be at least `8` elements in size and to pass that size to `getline`.

However, you're much better off using the `std::string` version of `getline` like so:

```
string expDate;
do{
  cout << "Enter experation (form mm/yyyy): ";
  getline(cin, expDate);
  // ...
}while(expEle != (expLast - 4));
```

Now you don't have to worry about buffer overflows.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Fixed the loop up quick!